# Rate the parameter and examine the centeredness of that parameter

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Distribution $X$ is described with density function 
$$  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\alpha}{c}(\frac{c}{x})^{\alpha +1},  & x>c \\
0, & x\le c
\end{cases}$$ where $\alpha >0$. Based on a sample of perimeter $n$, evaluate parameter $\alpha$. Examine the centeredness of that parameter.

Evaluation of parameter $\alpha $ gives $${\alpha}=\frac{n}{-n\ln c+\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\frac{x_i}{c}}$$

I am stuck with examining the centeredness of that parameter.
Evaluation of a parameter is centered if $E(\alpha)=\alpha$, else it is not.

We have:
$$E(\alpha)=E\left(\frac{n}{-n\ln c+\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\frac{x_i}{c}}\right)=nE\left(\frac{1}{-n\ln c+\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\frac{x_i}{c}}\right)$$
$$=n\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{y}f_Y(y)dy$$ where $Y=-n\ln c+\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\frac{x_i}{c}$

Let $$Z_i=\ln\frac{X_i}{c}$$

**Question:** How to evaluate $f_{Z_i}(z)$?

Than, from $f_{Z_i}(z)$ we have $f_{Y}(y)$, and finally, $E(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0):

CDF of $Z_i$ equals to
$$
F_{Z_i}(z)=\mathbb P(Z_i\leq z)=\mathbb P\left(\ln \frac{X_i}{c}<z\right)=\mathbb P\left(X_i<ce^z\right)=F_{X_i}(ce^z) \text{ for } z>0.
$$
Find derivative to get PDF:
$$
f_{Z_i}(z)=\left(F_{Z_i}(z)\right)'=ce^zf_{X_i}(ce^z)=\begin{cases}
\alpha e^{-\alpha z},  & z>0 \\
0, & z\le 0
\end{cases}
$$
This is exponential distribution.

Also check the estimator of $\alpha$: it should be 
$$
\hat{\alpha}=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\frac{x_i}{c}}=\frac{n}{-n\ln c+\sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i}
$$
Note also that the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ in denominator has Gamma distribution.